# How to reload the Flask app inside a lambda function once an s3 object has been updated?

Tags: flask, aws-lambda, zappa

I have a Flask app deployed on AWS lambda via Zappa. The app reads a csv file from s3, performs some data lookup operations and gives response to a GET request. Now, this csv file in s3 gets updated (replaced with an updated file with same name) everyday through an external process. My question is: How do I reload the flask application everyday to make sure that it starts reading from the updated file? I have been unable to do so as the Flask app reads the csv data file in memory and does not refresh it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set trigger on S3 bucket where your CSV files are stored. Set event trigger on update object. Add your lambda/flask app as a destination for this event. This way you can trigger lambda function whenever file is updated in S3.
For  reference
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-tutorial.html